# How to troubleshoot electronic issues?

Tags: arduino, resistors, relay

**My experiments** (using an arduino compatible board)

- Without resistor between IN and D5

  - 3V <-> VCC, the relay stays OFF
  - 5V <-> VCC, the relay stays ON
- With 10K ohms resistor between IN and D5

  - 5V <-> VCC, *everything worked*!

**My problem**

But after working for many hours (about half a day), the relay seemed to stopped receiving enough power to correctly switch the relay. I know the D5 pin received the on/off signal from the D5 pin as the status light on the relay board actually dimmed a bit (and I followed the D5 status from my arduino IDE console)

I've unplugged and re-plugged everything and now it's working again..

**Can it be related to the resistor value?**

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fLoazi.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This is the relay module I'm using :
https://www.amazon.ca/gp/product/B06XVV8W9B/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o02_s00

Comment: To answer the question of the title (How to troubleshoot): It's all about two things: Isolation of variables and understanding what could cause certain symptoms. Isolation of variables means you have to systematically rule out causes as you try to get to the root of the issue. Cause of symtoms refers to the fact that you need to understand what could cause the effect you are seeing based on what you know it should be doing. (Example: If you are working on a computer and have noticed that it has HDD freezes, you know you can probably rule out the battery of the wireless keyboard as a cause)

Comment: Your link to the relay module only shows an Amazon catalog page. You need to link to the *datasheet* which will show the circuit schematic. You should also link to the datasheet for your micro-controller board. Has it got 5 V outputs or 3.3 V?

Comment: @JorenVaes What if the bad battery causes the keyboard to repeatedly send the "[Sync all mounted filesystems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key)" magic key in linux??? Hm???

Comment: @pipe I was worried someone would point out how that could still be a cause... I spent a few minutes coming up with examples myself, only to just shoot them down with some unlikely edge-case situation

Comment: @Transistor it's mentioned on the product page that the working voltage is 5V and unfortunately I can't find the datasheet. The board have 2 possible output from 2 different pins: 5V and 3.3V, but same here, there are datasheets for the processor (ESP8266) but not for the board

Comment: @JorenVaes so I should wait to see if that happens again first and then try another relay board to exclude possibility that this component is the cause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The title of your question could be more specific. "How to troubleshot electronic issues" applies to almost every question asked here ;-)

Let's see if we can help you...

1 - The relay module has 5V in its codename, so the module's VCC has always be feed with 5V, or the relay's coin would not turn on, and there's no news that it didn't worked at 3v3. So, never connect the module to another voltage. If possible, measure the voltage with a multimeter to find if the source is really 5v that you expect it to be.

2 - But Wemos Lolin (I've just discovered what is it) works at 3V3. So, the output from WL's D5 pin, when "HIGH" is just 3V3, and I think that this is the reason why your circuit is not working properly

Even if it by chance it dit worked for some hours (just a temporary luck), you should never build a circuit relying on a 3v3 digital output to drive a 5V input (there's exceptions, but this is the kind of thing that your really should know what you're doing and would not be asking about this in stackexchange).

3 - The final answer is simple:

Wemos Lolin output and the relay module can not be directly connected, with or without a resistor, whatever the resistor value.

They only can be connected via a level-shift circuit, what can be a converter module like this [shift-level](http://www.dx.com/p/high-speed-8-bit-bidirectional-voltage-level-translator-module-for-arduino-417792), or a transistor. Google about:

wemos lolin to 5v relay module transistor level shift

trigger  5v relay module with 3.3v digital output

Good luck!

Comment: I'll take your comment about the title into consideration for my next questions. I thought that the 5v going to VCC was the actual voltage requirement (I'm new to electronic and have a lot to learn) and that D5 to IN could trigger with a lower voltage. No worries, I'm won't put high voltage on that relay before getting it checked by a professional, I'm just doing some experiments for a prototype. Your search terms helped me a lot to find something closer to what I would like to do. Thanks